# Azure Logic App with Dataverse connector returns Error 500 Value cannot be null

Tags: azure-logic-apps, microsoft-dynamics, dataverse

I'm trying to trigger a logic app when contacts are created in Dynamics 365. I've added a 'When a row is added, modified or deleted (preview)' trigger, using these settings:

- Environment: a sandbox environment
- Table name: Contacts
- Change type: Added
- Scope: Organization

The goal is to publish the received data to a Servicebus Topic, which is the only and final step in the logic flow. When running the trigger and adding a new contact in Dynamics, an error is thrown on the first trigger step:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: input\r\n   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(String input)",
    "source": "logic-apis-westeurope.azure-apim.net",
    "path": "choose[3]\\when[1]\\choose\\when[2]\\choose[3]\\when[1]\\return-response",
    "policyId": "",
    "clientRequestId": "947de49b-478b-47cf-9ea4-74459bb607db"
  }
}
```

The input somehow being null doesn't make any sense to me. Other than this the trigger seems to react very unpredictably to changes in Dynamics.

Answer (score 1):

I am using **When a row is added, modified or deleted (preview)** trigger in logic app and sending the data to service bus topic in following way.

**Workflow**-

[image]
[image]

Adding a new row in **Contacts** table or modifying any data is triggering the workflow and I am getting successful response.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Try to create the logic app from scratch or try to use different environment.